# C# Installer with WebView2 Runtime dependency

Tags: webview2

I am trying to follow the Microsoft documentation on how to add WebView2 Runtime as a dependency in the setup project using the [Evergreen Bootstrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution). The problem i have is that the installer always interrupts the installation from the start because it can't fine the Webview2 runtime even if it is already installed.  What am i missing?

Search Target Machine:
[image]

Launch Condition
[image]

Comment: I think the installer simply checks if there is a newer version available. Does it stop the installation or does it install the runtime again?

Comment: It stops the installation from the get go, then It asks for downloading the runtime again. The install never happens after the update has been downloaded. 
The installer works when i disable the Launch condition however the application obviously does not run without the WebView2 runtime

Comment: I suspect that the value "null" is incorrect. The instructions said "If this regkey doesn't exist, or if exists and is null or an empty string" ... not sure how to formulate this condition

Comment: Hi Poul Bak!. Do you think you have an idea on what is wrong with the installer? I could not figure out yet why it is not continuing the installation after the runtime was successfully installed

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer to this question but alternatively, we can run the "GetAvailableCoreWebView2BrowserVersionString" and evaluate whether the versionInfo is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

For RegKey, delete the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" part so that it's just "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}"

It knows to look in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE by the value you selected for your Root property, "vsdrrHKLM"

Lastly, for your Value property, try entering the name of any of the folders listed for this key. Mine works with "location" but "name", "pv", etc. should also work. It's simply checking that they exist. I think having it as null would mean it wants this key to have no values, which is not true, nor what we want :)